# Automation of printer operation, printing problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, printers

```
I can not set up automation to print the printer, the problem is printing a .png file, in the output it looks very fuzzy without a background and I can not set the size of an A4 size 72dpi
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZbUd.jpg)

```
def print_file(file_path):
    try:
        HORZRES = 8
        VERTRES = 10

        PHYSICALWIDTH = 110
        PHYSICALHEIGHT = 111

        printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

        hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
        hDC.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
        printable_area = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES)
        printer_size = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALWIDTH), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALHEIGHT)

        bmp = Image.open(file_path)
        if bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
            bmp = bmp.rotate(90)

        ratios = [1.0 * printable_area[0] / bmp.size[0], 1.0 * printable_area[1] / bmp.size[1]]
        scale = min(ratios)

        hDC.StartDoc(file_path)
        hDC.StartPage()

        dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
        scaled_width, scaled_height = [int(scale * i) for i in bmp.size]
        x1 = int((printer_size[0] - scaled_width) / 2)
        y1 = int((printer_size[1] - scaled_height) / 2)
        x2 = x1 + scaled_width
        y2 = y1 + scaled_height
        dib.draw(hDC.GetHandleOutput(), (x1, y1, x2, y2))

        hDC.EndPage()
        hDC.EndDoc()
        hDC.DeleteDC()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Errors:", e)
```

I tried changing constants HORZRES = 8, VERTRES = 10 to 595, 842, this causes the printer to just return a blank sheet without any printing

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the resolution (dpi) when creating the printer device context (DC) using `CreateDC`. I updated the code, hope it helps to get better output.

```py
import win32print
import win32ui
from PIL import Image, ImageWin

def print_file(file_path):
    try:
        printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

        hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
        hDC.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
        hDC.SetMapMode(win32ui.MM_TWIPS)
        hDC.SetDeviceSize((0, 0, 595, 842))  # Set A4 dimensions (72dpi)
        hDC.StartDoc(file_path)
        hDC.StartPage()

        bmp = Image.open(file_path)
        if bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
            bmp = bmp.rotate(90)

        dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
        dib.draw(hDC.GetHandleOutput(), (0, 0, 595 * 20, 842 * 20))  # Scale the image to fit A4 (20 twips per point)

        hDC.EndPage()
        hDC.EndDoc()
        hDC.DeleteDC()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Errors:", e)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code did not work for me, does not find a method SetDeviceSize in the module hDC, MM_TWIPS is also not found, but as I understand it was in the library with the constants

Answer (score 0):

The code didn't work at all, I tried to change it to something similar, but the same problem, the printer just returns a blank sheet.
Code:

```
    def print_file(file_path):
    try:
        printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

        hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
        hDC.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)

        #1 twip = 1/20 dot
        hDC.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)

        width_points = 595  
        height_points = 842 

        dpi_x = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.LOGPIXELSX)
        dpi_y = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.LOGPIXELSY)

        width_pixels = int(width_points * dpi_x / 72)
        height_pixels = int(height_points * dpi_y / 72)

        hDC.SetViewportOrg((0, 0))
        hDC.SetViewportExt((width_pixels, height_pixels))

        hDC.StartDoc(file_path)
        hDC.StartPage()

        bmp = Image.open(file_path)
        if bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
            bmp = bmp.rotate(90)

        dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
        dib.draw(hDC.GetHandleOutput(), (0, 0, width_pixels, height_pixels))

        hDC.EndPage()
        hDC.EndDoc()
        hDC.DeleteDC()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Errors:", e)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, so should not be posted as such.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone will need this code and will not agonize in searching for a solution to a similar problem

```
def print_file(file_path):

HORZRES = 8
VERTRES = 10

PHYSICALWIDTH = 110
PHYSICALHEIGHT = 111

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
hDC.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
printable_area = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES)
printer_size = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALWIDTH), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALHEIGHT)

bmp = Image.open(file_path).convert("L")
if bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
    bmp = bmp.rotate(90)

ratios = [1.0 * printable_area[0] / bmp.size[0], 1.0 * printable_area[1] / bmp.size[1]]
scale = min(ratios)

hDC.StartDoc(file_path)
hDC.StartPage()

dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
scaled_width, scaled_height = [int(scale * i) for i in bmp.size]
x1 = int((printer_size[0] - scaled_width) / 2)
y1 = int((printer_size[1] - scaled_height) / 2)
x2 = x1 + scaled_width
y2 = y1 + scaled_height
dib.draw(hDC.GetHandleOutput(), (x1, y1, x2, y2))

hDC.EndPage()
hDC.EndDoc()
hDC.DeleteDC()
```